Fitting nonlinear Bayesian regression with a summation term in brms
I'm trying to fit parameters for a Holling type II curve for multiple prey items. This takes the form:
$$
\frac{dP_i}{dt} = \frac{a_iP_i}{1 +\sum_j{a_jh_jP_j}}
$$
where $P_i$ is density of prey species $i$, $a_i$, is the "attack rate", and $h_i$ is the "handling time". I have data for $\frac{dP_i}{dt}$ and $P_i$, and would thus like to sample posterior distributions for parameter values for each $a_i$ and $h_i$.
If there are a relatively few number of species, it might be straightforward to make dummy variables for each $P$ and fit it that way, but this approach becomes untenable if there are many different $P_i$. Say we have hundreds of prey species, and we want $a_i$ and $h_i$ fit as random effects. Is there a way to use brms in r to specify this?
Picturing something like this:
    bf(dP ~ (a * P)/(1 + T),
       a ~ (1|species),
       T ~ sum(a * h * P),
       h ~ (1|species),
       nl = TRUE)

